# How do I start emacs with one horizontal split and one vertical split

Tags: start-up, window-splitting

Every time I start Emacs, I want two windows, side by side, and one terminal/shell window below them both, as shown here.[image]

Please help me with the necessary code to my init file.

Comment: ;; startup windowing
(split-window-vertically)
(split-window-horizontally)

Answer (score 1):

```
(defun split-my-way()
(interactive)
(split-window-below)
(split-window-right)
(other-window -1)
(eshell)
)

(call-interactively 'split-my-way)
```

Comment: The [`interactive`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Interactive.html) form comprises the first top-level form in a function body by convention.

Comment: This isn't giving results as expected.

Comment: That's all? You should give some details.

Comment: @Basil: sure, sorry I overlooked it.

Comment: After adding your code, it looks like this - http://www.imgpaste.net/image/De8qF

Comment: Well, it definitely works for me. Can you close other buffers and paste the above code into a new buffer and do `M-x eval-buffer`?

Comment: The result is - "Symbol's value as variable is void: Welcome

Comment: I have no idea what `Welcome` comes from - definitely not from the code I posted.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk  I guess it is from Emacs splash screen.